# PhpStorm Code Style no first level indentation after class tag, possible?

Tags: php, phpstorm, indentation

Is it possible to tell PhpStorm that I do not want to start a new level of indention after the class tag?

I've been looking all over and there is a lot of options in `Settings>Editor>Code Style>PHP` but I haven't been able to find this there.

This would be an example:

```
<?php

class test {

public function testFunction() {
    //Look ma, first level of indention!
}

}
```

Comment: Why would you want to ruin indentation? Have you tried selecting all methods and hitting `shift + tab`?

Comment: This makes your code hard to read. I would prefer to keep indention after class brackets.

Comment: [PSR-1](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/) and [SPR-2](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) use/suggest using proper indentation for any stuff declared inside class declaration. https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/tree/master/accepted

Comment: I agree this is suboptimal but someone in my team suggested it to make github diff's more readable in that it tells you what function you are inside of instead of what class.

shift + tab seems to be the only solution atm, although a manual one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such option.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-12068 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress. So far this ticket is not planned for any specific future version.